# Getting same values on mobx reaction listening an ObservableList

Tags: flutter, dart, mobx

i'm using **mobx** package on **flutter**. (all on latest stable version)

I'm trying to use the **reaction** to list the updates of an **ObservableList**, the **reaction** is called only once time, because next on the calls, the new value and old value are equal and I can't understand why. All the other parts of the code are running as expected.

Example code:

```
abstract class _TesteControllerBase with Store {
  _TesteControllerBase() {
    reaction((_) => list, (list) {
      // print(list.length);
    }, equals: (newValue, oldValue) {
      print('newValue: $newValue');
      print('oldValue: $oldValue');

      return newValue == oldValue;
    });
  }

  @observable
  ObservableList<String> list = ObservableList();

  @action
  addNew() {
    list.add('${list.length + 1}');
  }
}
```

Prints are returning the same value to newValue and oldValue (image attached).

Image of running code:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is that you **compare arrays**, which means that you **compare their references in memory**, not their content. Simple example:

```
var arr1=[];
var arr2=[];
arr1 === arr2 // false
```

The content of the arrays is the same, but their addresses in the memory is different.

So, when you track changes for `list`, what you are tracking is if the reference is changed. That's why it works only the first time, when it has no address in the memory yet(`null`) and after that the array is initialized.

What you can do is to `stringify` the array, so every change in it will be tracked(addition, deletion, update of elements). Your reaction will look like this:

```
 reaction((_) => JSON.stringify(list), (stringifiedList) {
      // print(JSON.parse(stringifiedList).length);
    });
```

You **don't need the equals** function now, because internally mobx makes the comparison for you

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it makes sense, I'll try this.

Comment: If there is still an issue, let me know. If it is working, you can approve the answer.